# Console Closes on Enter Press C#

Tags: c#, console, enter

I am having trouble with my console application(C#). I want to make it so when you input a car brand it will return the total value off all those cars i have done that successfully. What i am having trouble with is that i want them to be able to input another car brand and the program return the total amount again without it closing. Right now it closes the second time someone hits enter. Please help!
My code below.

```
 namespace Cars
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Car> myCars = new List<Car>() {
            new Car() { Make="BMW", Model="550i", Color=CarColor.Blue, StickerPrice=55000, Year=2009 },
            new Car() { Make="Toyota", Model="4Runner", Color=CarColor.White, StickerPrice=35000, Year=2010 },
            new Car() { Make="BMW", Model="745li", Color=CarColor.Black, StickerPrice=75000, Year=2008 },
            new Car() { Make="Ford", Model="Escape", Color=CarColor.White, StickerPrice=28000, Year=2008 },
            new Car() { Make="BMW", Model="550i", Color=CarColor.Black, StickerPrice=57000, Year=2010 }
            };
        Console.WriteLine("Type \"all\" to see total value of all cars");
        Console.WriteLine("Type \"bmw\" to see total value of all bmws");
        Console.WriteLine("Type \"toyota\" to see total value of all Toyotas");
        Console.WriteLine("Type \"ford\" to see total value of all Fords");
        string userValue = Console.ReadLine();
        if (userValue == "all")
        {
            var _orderedCars = myCars.OrderByDescending(p => p.Year);
            foreach (var car in _orderedCars)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} - {2} - {3:C}", car.Make, car.Model, car.Year, car.StickerPrice);
            }
            var sum = _orderedCars.Sum(p => p.StickerPrice);
            Console.WriteLine("{0:C}", sum);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else if (userValue == "bmw")
        {
            var _bmws = myCars.Where(car => car.Make == "BMW");

            foreach (var car in _bmws)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} - {2}- {3:C}", car.Make, car.Model, car.Year, car.StickerPrice);
            }
            var sum = _bmws.Sum(p => p.StickerPrice);
            Console.WriteLine("{0:C}", sum);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else if (userValue == "toyota")
        {
            var _toyotaCars = myCars.Where(car => car.Make == "Toyota");

            foreach (var car in _toyotaCars)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} - {2} - {3:C}", car.Make, car.Model, car.Year, car.StickerPrice);
            }
            var sum = _toyotaCars.Sum(p => p.StickerPrice);
            Console.WriteLine("{0:C}", sum);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else if (userValue == "ford")
        {
            var _fordCars = myCars.Where(car => car.Make == "Ford");
            foreach (var car in _fordCars)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} - {2} - {3:C}", car.Make, car.Model, car.Year, car.StickerPrice);
            }
            var sum = _fordCars.Sum(p => p.StickerPrice);
            Console.WriteLine("{0:C}", sum);
            Console.ReadLine();
         }
         else
         {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
         }
      }

    class Car
    {
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public double StickerPrice { get; set; }
        public CarColor Color { get; set; }
    }

    enum CarColor
    {
       White,
       Black,
       Red,
       Blue,
       Yellow
    }
}
```

}

Comment: use a `while` loop to wrap your code (of course not all the code) and `break` it when user wants to exit.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is written to terminate after the user enters the first value and the results are displayed. You need some kind of looping mechanism around the the main program to keep it going. Something along the lines of:

```
        bool readyToExit = false;
        while (!readyToExit)
        {
            /* 
             * ...
             * Display your menu here.
             * ...
             */

            String userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            ProcessInput(userInput); // Move all your main logic into a new ProcessInput method.

            readyToExit = userInput.Equals("quit", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
        }
```

Comment: modulization should always be +1'd ;)

Comment: Thanks, i just had to get rid of the Console.ReadLine(); in if statements and now it runs smooth. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First wrap everything in a while loop.  Then, use logic to space out the statement for easier readability.  Finally, break out of the while loop when the user enters nothing or something other than the valid choices.

```
 namespace Cars
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                                List<Car> myCars = new List<Car>() {
                new Car() { Make="BMW", Model="550i", Color=CarColor.Blue, StickerPrice=55000,     Year=2009 },
            new Car() { Make="Toyota", Model="4Runner", Color=CarColor.White, StickerPrice=35000, Year=2010 },
            new Car() { Make="BMW", Model="745li", Color=CarColor.Black, StickerPrice=75000, Year=2008 },
            new Car() { Make="Ford", Model="Escape", Color=CarColor.White, StickerPrice=28000, Year=2008 },
            new Car() { Make="BMW", Model="550i", Color=CarColor.Black, StickerPrice=57000, Year=2010 }
            };
            while (true)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Type \"all\" to see total value of all cars");
                Console.WriteLine("Type \"bmw\" to see total value of all bmws");
                Console.WriteLine("Type \"toyota\" to see total value of all Toyotas");
                Console.WriteLine("Type \"ford\" to see total value of all Fords");
                string userValue = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                if (userValue == "all")
                {
                    var _orderedCars = myCars.OrderByDescending(p => p.Year);
                    foreach (var car in _orderedCars)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} - {2} - {3:C}", car.Make, car.Model, car.Year, car.StickerPrice);
                    }
                    var sum = _orderedCars.Sum(p => p.StickerPrice);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0:C}", sum);
                }
                else if (userValue == "bmw")
                {
                    var _bmws = myCars.Where(car => car.Make == "BMW");

                    foreach (var car in _bmws)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} - {2}- {3:C}", car.Make, car.Model, car.Year, car.StickerPrice);
                    }
                    var sum = _bmws.Sum(p => p.StickerPrice);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0:C}", sum);
                }
                else if (userValue == "toyota")
                {
                    var _toyotaCars = myCars.Where(car => car.Make == "Toyota");

                    foreach (var car in _toyotaCars)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} - {2} - {3:C}", car.Make, car.Model, car.Year, car.StickerPrice);
                    }
                    var sum = _toyotaCars.Sum(p => p.StickerPrice);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0:C}", sum);
                }
                else if (userValue == "ford")
                {
                    var _fordCars = myCars.Where(car => car.Make == "Ford");
                    foreach (var car in _fordCars)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} - {2} - {3:C}", car.Make, car.Model, car.Year, car.StickerPrice);
                    }
                    var sum = _fordCars.Sum(p => p.StickerPrice);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0:C}", sum);
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exit program (Y/N)?");
                    var answer = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (answer.ToString().ToUpper() != "N")
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        class Car
        {
            public string Make { get; set; }
            public string Model { get; set; }
            public int Year { get; set; }
            public double StickerPrice { get; set; }
            public CarColor Color { get; set; }
        }

        enum CarColor
        {
            White,
            Black,
            Red,
            Blue,
            Yellow
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: start the while after the list declaration, it doesn't need to be repeated

Comment: Good point! Since it is already in memory and nothing new is added, there is no reason to instantiate it each time.

Answer (score 0):

you need a while encapsulating your main logic. this while would be exited by, say, typing q, otherwise it would loop through your current main again.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Car> myCars = new List<Car>() {
        new Car() { Make="BMW", Model="550i", Color=CarColor.Blue, StickerPrice=55000, Year=2009 },
        new Car() { Make="Toyota", Model="4Runner", Color=CarColor.White, StickerPrice=35000, Year=2010 },
        new Car() { Make="BMW", Model="745li", Color=CarColor.Black, StickerPrice=75000, Year=2008 },
        new Car() { Make="Ford", Model="Escape", Color=CarColor.White, StickerPrice=28000, Year=2008 },
        new Car() { Make="BMW", Model="550i", Color=CarColor.Black, StickerPrice=57000, Year=2010 }
        };
        bool ohPleaseLetMeDoItAgain = true;
        while (ohPleaseLetMeDoItAgain)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type \"all\" to see total value of all cars");
            Console.WriteLine("Type \"bmw\" to see total value of all bmws");
            Console.WriteLine("Type \"toyota\" to see total value of all Toyotas");
            Console.WriteLine("Type \"ford\" to see total value of all Fords");
            Console.WriteLine("Type \"q\" to quit");
            string userValue = Console.ReadLine();
            if (userValue == "all")
            {
                var _orderedCars = myCars.OrderByDescending(p => p.Year);
                foreach (var car in _orderedCars)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} - {2} - {3:C}", car.Make, car.Model, car.Year, car.StickerPrice);
                }
                var sum = _orderedCars.Sum(p => p.StickerPrice);
                Console.WriteLine("{0:C}", sum);
            }
            else if (userValue == "bmw")
            {
                var _bmws = myCars.Where(car => car.Make == "BMW");

                foreach (var car in _bmws)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} - {2}- {3:C}", car.Make, car.Model, car.Year, car.StickerPrice);
                }
                var sum = _bmws.Sum(p => p.StickerPrice);
                Console.WriteLine("{0:C}", sum);
            }
            else if (userValue == "toyota")
            {
                var _toyotaCars = myCars.Where(car => car.Make == "Toyota");

                foreach (var car in _toyotaCars)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} - {2} - {3:C}", car.Make, car.Model, car.Year, car.StickerPrice);
                }
                var sum = _toyotaCars.Sum(p => p.StickerPrice);
                Console.WriteLine("{0:C}", sum);
            }
            else if (userValue == "ford")
            {
                var _fordCars = myCars.Where(car => car.Make == "Ford");
                foreach (var car in _fordCars)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} - {2} - {3:C}", car.Make, car.Model, car.Year, car.StickerPrice);
                }
                var sum = _fordCars.Sum(p => p.StickerPrice);
                Console.WriteLine("{0:C}", sum);
            }
            else
            {
                ohPleaseLetMeDoItAgain = !userValue.Equals("q");
            }
        }
    }

    class Car
    {
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public double StickerPrice { get; set; }
        public CarColor Color { get; set; }
    }

    enum CarColor
    {
        White,
        Black,
        Red,
        Blue,
        Yellow
    }

}
```

Comment: then it is a good Friday, now go hit the pub your job is done!

Comment: Haha uhh, im 15 years old.

Comment: well slap me silly, I feel old now, you can still get a coke at the pub!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your code inside a while, a do while or a for. You can also use a function to separate your cycle from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If it works for one and you want it to do many, you need to add a loop around the part of your code that you want repeated...

Answer (score 0):

Put a loop around your logic and Just Before your main terminates put a read function

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {

  // add item to list
   }

Console.Read()

}
```